# Is it possible to install ConTeXt on Windows without admin rights?

Tags: installing, windows, context-mkiv

Well, the title says all.

On contextgarden it is written:

NOTE: You will need admin rights to your Windows to manage the installation process. If you don't have that, get somebody who does.

Is this absolute, or is there a solution for a portable version, which can be installed and maintained without admin rights?

I am using Win7 and have MixTeX portable installed.

Comment: Untested, but [TeX Live portable](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) might support ConTeXt well enough for your purposes.

Comment: Not sure which contextgarden page you are referring to. Simply follow the [command line method](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Command_line_method) to install context standalone. You do not need admin rights for that.

Comment: @Aditya I refferred to this page: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Windows_Installation:_ConTeXt_Suite_with_SciTe. I also tried the to install the standalone version, but got timeouts when 'rsync' tried to finalise the installation. Most likely, port 873 is not open on my computer, and as far as I know, I need admin rights to open the port. I installed ConTeXt standalone on a computer where I have admin rights, and then it worked. That computer is not my daily working PC, so it was not much help.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If yes, may you share the steps?

Comment: @TeXnician I did not find any solution for my problem. You can install Context without admin right, but then rsync does not function, A possible solution may be to install it on a separate computer where you have admin rights, and, after each update, copy the installation to the computer where you do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I newer got a clear answer, I summarise my finding:

I followed the command line method to install ConTeXt standalone, and was able to install the basis without admin rights. When 'rsync' tried to finalise the installation, but got timeouts errors from `rsync`. Port 873, which is used by `rsync`, is probably not open for communication on my computer, and I need admin rights to open it. I installed ConTeXt standalone on a computer where I have admin rights, and then `rsync` worked.

A work-a-round may be to install ConTeXt on a computer where you *have* admin rights, and, after each update, copy the installation to the computer where you *do not have* admin rights.