# ConTeXt unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'

Tags: windows, context-lmtx

#### Updates & Inclusion of info asked in comments:

(in reverse chronological order)

##### 4. (self) Run logs after `cp texlivecnf.lua texmfcnf.lua`

On looking at `selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c/` (as the log pointed out, and Max Chernoff asked for `2.` below), it contained: `contextcnf.lua  readme.txt  texlivecnf.lua`. So, i copy-pasted `texlivecnf.lua` and renamed to `texmfcnf.lua` and ran the `context --version` again. this time the run log is only 2 lines:

```shell
$ context --version
resolvers       | caches | path '<...>/tex/texmf-var' created
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'

$ mtxrun --generate
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOLOC' set to '<...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin'
  ...
  <lots of things>
  ...
system          | lua | dumping '.../tex/texmf-var/luametatex-cache/context/....lua' into '<...>/tex/texmf-var/luametatex-cache/context/....lud' stripped
resolvers       | caching | 'files' compiled to '<...>/tex/texmf-var/luametatex-cache/context/.../
trees/....lud'
mtxrun          |
mtxrun          | elapsed lua time: 0.111 seconds

$ context --version
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
```

##### 3. (self) Run logs after manual extract of `texmf-context/`

I might be jumping the guns too early, but anyways, I tried replacing the `texmf-context` dir with the manual extract from `texmf-context.zip` (112 MiB), and thereafter, the stdout on `context --version` is now indeed changed. It now says `configuration files already identified;; skipping configuration file 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c/texmfcnf.lua' (no valid format)` rather than `warning: no lua configuration files found`

```
$ context --version
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | configuration files already identified
resolvers       | resolving | skipping configuration file 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c/texmfcnf.lua' (no valid format)
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
```

##### 2. Contents of `texmf-context` directory

[image]

I would assume that after this, install logs (in admin mode, in fresh directory) would also help, as the obvious question coming to mind after seeing this above screenshot is
"why did that happen like that".

```
D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64>install.bat
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
mtx-install     | server   : lmtx.pragma-ade.com
mtx-install     | instance : install-lmtx
mtx-install     | platform : win64
mtx-install     | system   : windows
mtx-install     | fetching 'http://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx//texmf.zip'
mtx-install     | unzipping 'texmf.zip'
  70 files of  703 done,    6960406 bytes, 0.108 seconds
 140 files of  703 done,   10371456 bytes, 0.190 seconds
 210 files of  703 done,   14124718 bytes, 0.266 seconds
 280 files of  703 done,   19504148 bytes, 0.349 seconds
 350 files of  703 done,   24662280 bytes, 0.437 seconds
 420 files of  703 done,   33169752 bytes, 0.537 seconds
 490 files of  703 done,   40851921 bytes, 0.651 seconds
 560 files of  703 done,   47678981 bytes, 0.800 seconds
 630 files of  703 done,   68321769 bytes, 0.959 seconds
 700 files of  703 done,   86640590 bytes, 1.110 seconds
 703 files of  703 done,   86661272 bytes, 1.113 seconds
mtx-install     | fetching 'http://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx//texmf-context.zip'
mtx-install     | unzipping 'texmf-context.zip'
 528 files of 5281 done,   87825652 bytes, 1.655 seconds
1056 files of 5281 done,   95725794 bytes, 2.293 seconds
1584 files of 5281 done,  115588528 bytes, 2.940 seconds
2112 files of 5281 done,  123849099 bytes, 3.430 seconds
2640 files of 5281 done,  141160640 bytes, 4.349 seconds
3168 files of 5281 done,  150477455 bytes, 4.901 seconds
3696 files of 5281 done,  158009242 bytes, 5.485 seconds
4224 files of 5281 done,  167500225 bytes, 5.975 seconds
4752 files of 5281 done,  174233998 bytes, 6.481 seconds
5280 files of 5281 done,  180899946 bytes, 7.075 seconds
5281 files of 5281 done,  180912843 bytes, 7.077 seconds
mtx-install     | installing tex/texmf-win64, 6 files
mtx-install     | skipping tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe
mtx-install     | new      :  18 % :     1315 : tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.lua
mtx-install     | new      :  36 % :  3046912 : tex/texmf-win64/bin/luametatex.exe
mtx-install     | new      :  78 % :  7249920 : tex/texmf-win64/bin/luatex.exe
mtx-install     | skipping tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.exe
mtx-install     | new      : 100 % :   701600 : tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.lua
mtx-install     | current  : <...>
mtx-install     | target   : <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin
mtx-install     | removing : mtxrun.exe
mtx-install     | removing : context.exe
mtx-install     | copied   : mtxrun.exe
mtx-install     | copied   : context.exe
mtx-install     | xbit set : <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/luametatex.exe
mtx-install     | xbit set : <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/luatex.exe
mtx-install     | xbit set : <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.exe
mtx-install     | xbit set : <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe
mtx-install     | running: <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.exe --generate
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOLOC' set to '<...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTODIR' set to '<...>/tex/texmf-win64'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOPARENT' set to '<...>/tex'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMFCNF' set to ''
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMF' set to ''
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXOS' set to 'texmf-win64'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | using configuration specification 'home:texmf/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          |
mtxrun          | elapsed lua time: 23.604 seconds
mtx-install     | running: <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe --make en
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
mtx-install     | running: <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe --luatex --generate
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
mtx-install     | running: <...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe --luatex --make en
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
mtx-install     |
mtx-install     | tex/texmf            :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
mtx-install     | tex/texmf-context    :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
mtx-install     | tex/texmf-win64      :    6 files with  17093571 bytes installed
mtx-install     |
mtx-install     | ConTeXt LMTX with LuaMetaTeX is still experimental and when you get a crash this
mtx-install     | can be due to a mismatch between Lua bytecode and the engine. In that case you can
mtx-install     | try the following:
mtx-install     |
mtx-install     |   - wipe the texmf-cache directory
mtx-install     |   - run: mtxrun --generate
mtx-install     |   - run: context --make
mtx-install     |
mtx-install     | When that doesn't solve the problem, ask on the mailing list (ntg-context@ntg.nl).
mtx-install     |
mtx-install     | update, done


Updating installer:

        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

When you want to use context, you need to initialize the tree with:

  D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\setpath.bat

You can associate this command with a shortcut to the cmd prompt. Alternatively
you can add

  D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\tex\texmf-win64\bin

to your PATH variable. If you run from an editor you can specify the full path
to mtxrun.exe:

  D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\tex\texmf-win64\bin\mtxrun.exe --autogenerate --script context --autopdf ...

If you also want to run LuaTeX and MkIV you can provide --luatex but first the file
database has to be generated (this time with context and not mtxrun):
.
  context --luatex --generate
  context --luatex --make
.
The following settings were used:

  server   : lmtx.contextgarden.net,lmtx.pragma-ade.com,lmtx.pragma-ade.nl
  instance : install-lmtx
  extras   :
  ownpath  : D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\
  platform : win64
```

##### 1. Full log of `mtxrun --generate` (per the instructions by @Max Chernoff in comments):

```
D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64>D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\tex\texmf-win64\bin\luametatex.exe --luaonly D:\StandalonePrograms\context-win64\bin\mtxrun.lua --generate
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOLOC' set to '<...>/tex/texmf-win64/bin'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTODIR' set to '<...>/tex/texmf-win64'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOPARENT' set to '<...>/tex'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMFCNF' set to ''
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMF' set to ''
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXOS' set to 'texmf-win64'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | using configuration specification 'home:texmf/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'C:/Users/admin0/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          |
mtxrun          | elapsed lua time: 0.015 seconds
```

### Original description:

#### Summary:

- `context --version` not running on windows; & showing errors like:
- `unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'`
- `the resolver databases are not present or outdated`

#### Duplicate searches:

- this [tug mailing list thread#49028](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2023-March/thread.html#49028) mentions same issue - but in context of a different method of installation (involving docker images? which got fixed upstream)
- this [TEX.SE comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195580/#comment453727_195580) redirects to the standalone cli install instructions, but for *now outdated* MkIV distribution.
- this [TEX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653913/) is again for texlive
- the [TEX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474246/a#474514) mentions `mtxrun --generate` which generate a subset of errors from already tried steps (namely: "variable set to", "looking for", "no lua config", "no TEXMF path") and didn't succeed.
- [context,windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows%20context) tag only contained 10-11 questions from last decade

#### Installation:

- Following this ConTeXt LMTX official [Installation](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation) guide,
- I downloaded the "Windows > x86 64bits" ([context-win64.zip](https://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx/context-win64.zip)), and extracted
- then ran the `install.bat` via `cmd` shell on wezterm as normal user (non-admin)
- I then manually added the indicated path (no spaces) `...\context-win64\tex\texmf-win64\bin` to environment `PATH` variable

#### Usage Logs:

Now command logs on trying to actually run it:

```console
$ # https://wiki.contextgarden.net/First_Document
$ context --version
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '<USERPROFILE>/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
  ...
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '<...>/context-win64/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'  
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
  ...
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'

$ mtxrun --version
mtxrun          | ConTeXt TDS Runner Tool 1.32
mtxrun          | source path

$ luametatex --version
This is LuaMetaTeX, Version 2.10.11
 ...
```

#### Environment & OS:

- OS: Win 10 22H2
- shell used: bash (MSYS2)
- Existing LaTeX distribution: yes, MiKTeX (it doesn't provide context with it)

#### Installation Summary

- the `install.bat` script performs *mainly* following 2 actions:

  1. `mtxrun --script .../mtx-install.lua`
  2. `copy /Y ... ...`

```batch
"%OWNPATH%bin\mtxrun" --script "%OWNPATH%/bin/mtx-install.lua" --update --server=%LMTXSERVER% --instance=%LMTXINSTANCE% --extras="%LMTXEXTRAS%" %*

copy /Y "%OWNPATH%tex\texmf-%PLATFORM%\bin\mtxrun.exe"                   "%OWNPATH%\bin\mtxrun.exe"
copy /Y "%OWNPATH%tex\texmf-context\scripts\context\lua\mtxrun.lua"      "%OWNPATH%\bin\mtxrun.lua"
copy /Y "%OWNPATH%tex\texmf-context\scripts\context\lua\mtx-install.lua" "%OWNPATH%\bin\mtx-install.lua"
```

##### Summary for 2nd step:

```
Updating installer:

        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

##### Summary for 1st step:

- the links it generated to fetch files were (sic, double slashes):

  - http://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx//texmf.zip (51 MiB)
  - http://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx//texmf-context.zip (112 MiB)
- following set sequence (reformatted) was repeated some 5 times in first step:

```
resolvers       | resolving |
    looking for regular ...
    looking for fallback ...
    warning: no lua configuration files found
    no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
```

- other notable lines in first step were things like below (reformatted):

```
mtx-install     |: 
    installing tex/texmf-win64, 6 files
    xbit set : <...>/context-win64/tex/texmf-win64/bin/luametatex.exe
    running: <...>/context-win64/tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.exe --generate
resolvers       | resolving |:
    variable 'SELFAUTOLOC' set to '<...>/context-win64/tex/texmf-win64/bin'
    variable 'SELFAUTODIR' set to '<...>/context-win64/tex/texmf-win64'
    variable 'SELFAUTOPARENT' set to '<...>/context-win64/tex'
    variable 'TEXMFCNF' set to ''
    variable 'TEXMF' set to ''
    variable 'TEXOS' set to 'texmf-win64'
mtx-install     |:
    tex/texmf            :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
    tex/texmf-context    :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
    tex/texmf-win64      :    6 files with  17079747 bytes installed
mtx-install     |:
    [in case of crash] try the following:
      - wipe the texmf-cache directory
      - run: mtxrun --generate
      - run: context --make
update, done
```

Comment: I don't use Windows. But on https://www.pragma-ade.com/install.htm it is said to best run the setup.bat as Administrator. There should also be a setpath.bat to run.

Comment: i have manually done setpath - so, there's no need of running `setpath.bat`; i will retry with running `install.bat` as admin; but as i am limited by network bandwidth; i will have to download those zips before hand, and figure out way to make `install.bat` or worse `mtx-install.lua` use those existing zips from current dir

> _https://pragma-ade.com/install.htm says run setup.bat as admin; also setpath.bat_ - mickep

Comment: `mtxrun --generate` should fix this, but you said that that didn't work. Can you edit in the full output of that command?

Comment: You can also try running it with the full path, `C:\path\to\context\context-win64\bin\luametatex --luaonly C:\path\to\context\context-win64\bin\mtxrun.lua --generate`, although I doubt that that will fix anything.

Comment: i retried running install.bat as admin in same dir, but iguess it reoperated on existing files; so, i re-extracted context....zip into a new directory, and ran install.bat there as admin. but same logs followed.

Comment: @MaxChernoff i will add mtxrun --generate's log & will full path; just a nuance, it's not in C: drive (if that matters)

Comment: and also, the `luametatex` ain't in bin, but rather in `tex\texmf-win64\bin\luametatex.exe`

Comment: @user8395964 Counterintuitively, that's the expected place for `luametatex.exe`. The top-level `bin/` is only for the installer/updater, `tex/texmf-<platform>/bin/` is where the runtime binaries go.

Comment: @user8395964 That log suggests that your binaries are correctly installed, and the variables all look correct, but your `texmf` tree is either incomplete or in the wrong location. I'm not really sure how or why that would have happened though? What files do you have in your `D:/StandalonePrograms/context-win64/tex/texmf-context/web2c/` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151058/discussion-between-user8395964-and-max-chernoff).

Comment: ignore the "chat invitation" - i was just seeing what happens on clicking this banner of _"Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"_ as i never had that privilege on SO network to join chat before.

Comment: @MaxChernoff hi! thanks for looking in. yeah - the whole of `texmf-context` directory is blank - i have added the screenshot in the question itself. i suspected smth was awry with this - as in the install logs, it said `mtx-install     | tex/texmf-context    :    0 files with         0 bytes installed` - so, it seems the problem is in unzipping

Answer (score 0):

These steps do not solve whole of the problem, but only some part of it.

Motivated/driven by:

> *What files do you have in your `context-win64/tex/texmf-context/web2c/` folder?* 
> @Max Chernoff at [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707701/#comment1759815_707701)

Given commands use GNU utils, use those via `msys2` or `git-bash`; but the worded instructions should be clear to indicate file explorer actions required.

1. Navigate to directory of installation. Check contents of the `./tex/tex-context/` dir:

```
$ # ls -1sap tex/tex-context/     #  is better form of  this

$ eza -l -aa --no-time tex/tex-context/
d----    - .
d----    - ..
-a---    0 colors
-a---    0 context
-a--- 2.4k context-readme.txt
-a---    0 doc
  ...
-a---    0 web2c
```

2. See  all 0s. Replace those with contents of `texmf-context.zip`
   (" http://lmtx.pragma-ade.com/install-lmtx//texmf-context.zip "<sup>[1]</sup>). Now, try to check contents of said directory again.

```
$ rm -I tex/tex-context/*
rm: remove 10 arguments? y

$ unzip -q ../texmf-context.zip

$ ls tex/texmf-context/web2c/
contextcnf.lua  readme.txt  texlivecnf.lua
```

3. In that dir, copy paste `texlivecnf.lua` as `texmfcnf.lua`

```
$ cd tex/texmf-context/web2c/

$ cp texlivecnf.lua texmfcnf.lua
```

4. Try running `context --version` now

```
$ context --version
resolvers       | caches | path '<...>/tex/texmf-var' created
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
```

Only this error remains now: `mtxrun | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'`

---

<sub>[^1]: This link is took from logs of last `install.bat` run.</sub>

Comment: `cp texlivecnf.lua texmfcnf.lua` should _definitely_ not be necessary (and will likely break something). I'd try undoing that, then run `mtxrun --generate` followed by `context --make`.

Comment: lol, i knew it was a hack. but i don't know why i like trying such coercions if things don't work. i will try as instructed now. also, is there somewhere better to talk about this? (github/gitlab/telegram/sourceforge/zulip chat/etc) - as it's more like an issue tracker discussion which makes me constantly running in fear of SE mod overlords while posting here.

Comment: or maybe that _SE chat_ thingy too?

Comment: @MaxChernoff it still repeats the same things: `looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua'`, `looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua'`, `found fallback configuration file 'D:/StandalonePrograms/context-win64/tex/texmf-context/web2c/contextcnf.lua';;;; looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path 'D:/StandalonePrograms/context-win64/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c' ;;;; skipping configuration file 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c/texmfcnf.lua' (no valid format) ;;;; no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)` - ends

Comment: The [ConTeXt mailing list `ntg-context@ntg.nl`](https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/latest) is the "official" place for ConTeXt discussions/bug reports/etc. Hans (the main developer) usually fixes issues reported there fairly quickly, although it can be pretty random at times. The TeX.SE mods are _much_ more lenient than the rest of SE, so I wouldn't worry too much about the "too many comments" warnings.